# Linked in auto login & share

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I try to develop an php application that share into linkedin page . When the user submit a post in my site its automatically post it to my linkedin page without ask user to sign in.
in another words: I need a feature like "offline access in facebook".

thanks

Comment: So you want unauthenticated people to be able to post data to *your* LinkedIn profile? Sure that it is a good idea? They could post anything to your professional profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtain oauth token - the end user should grant permissions

POST your messages to users wall using REST API and obtained token

http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1252